# How to join two collection of MongoDB using laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-8

I want to join two collection of mongoDB in laravel 8. I have used jessanger package for connect mongoDB & laravel.
Please help me to get out of it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there the way to do aggregation query in the library or DRM that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the aggregation framework provided by MongoDB.

**`Following the steps`**

step 1: Create a new controller or open an existing one where you want to perform the join operation.

step 2: Import classes at the top of your controller.

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Facades\MongoDB;
use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;
```

step 3: Define a method in your controller

```
public function joinCollections()
{
    $pipeline = [
        [
            '$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'collection1', // Replace with the name of your first collection
                'localField' => 'fieldToJoin', // Replace with the field to join on in the current collection
                'foreignField' => 'fieldToJoin', // Replace with the field to join on in the other collection
                'as' => 'joinedData' // Replace with the name of the field to store the joined data
            ]
        ],
        // Add additional stages if needed
    ];

    $results = MongoDB::collection('collection2') // Replace with the name of your second collection
        ->raw()
        ->aggregate($pipeline)
        ->toArray();

    return $results;
}
```

step 4: Customize the $pipeline array to suit your specific join requirements.

step 5: Replace '**collection1**', '**fieldToJoin**', '**collection2**', and '**fieldToJoin**' with the actual names of your collections and fields.

step 6: Access the **joinedData** field in the result to retrieve the joined data.

hope it's helpful.